# Using for_each , copy with string

Tags: c++, string, stl, iterator

I have some problem with program maybe some one can help me . So:

```
int main() {
    std::string col = "maly tekst"
    for_each(/* FILL IN #2*/ f());
    copy(/*FILL IN #3*/);
    std::cout << col; }
```

Output should be : TSKET YLAM
I know that i need to use Functor so i made something like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
class f{
public:
void operator() (char &k)const
{
   k = toupper(k);
}
};
int main(){
std::string col = "maly tekst";
for_each(col.begin(),col.end(),f());
copy(col.rbegin(),col.rend(),back_inserter(col));
std::cout << col << std::endl;
}
```

But now when i run it it returns :

```
MALY TEKSTTSKET YLAM
```

Can some one point me on right way , or help me with this example program ?

Thanks

E: Forgot to add that I can only use this functions in main , I cant add anything new

Comment: You are inserting into the back of the same string.

Comment: If your functor is as shown, you need to make the operator public. If it is not as shown, I suggest you change that habit.

Comment: Sory i forget to add public: its is public now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use std::copy to replace original container if you can't use `std::reverse`. To print col with `reverse order`, another work around is to copy `col` to `stream iterator` directly.

```
for_each(col.begin(),col.end(),f());
std::copy(col.rbegin(), col.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, ""));
```

Comment: I thought that it is good answer. 
Output should be TSKET YLAM
so we cant use copy to write that , imo we must use copy to change the string but i dont know how ...

Answer (score 2):

```
std::for_each(col.begin(),col.end(),f()); // as before
std::reverse(col.begin(), col.end());
```

Comment: Sory mate but i can use only this functions in main .

Comment: @Silwest do you need to reverse in place, or can you copy into another string?

Comment: That is good question , but i think i need to reveres it in place because i cant add anything new in main Only in place where FILL IN is .

Comment: @Silwest I can't think of a nice way to do it with ``std::copy``.

Comment: Here are some hints at an ugly way to solve the problem while still 'using' `std::copy()` - make the `std::copy()` essentially a no-op except for evaluating its arguments (easy to do). A comma operator hack can be used to force evaluation of an expression that doesn't evaluate to a useful type - the result of the left sub-expression is thrown away, but the side-effects aren't. And `reverse()` is something that doesn't evaluate to anything useful for a `std:copy()` argument, but the side-effect is exactly what's wanted. Put these together and homework's done. I hope I haven't said too much.